# How do I merge two Dashboard data sources in grafana

Tags: grafana

I would like to re-use a query between panels -- ideally between library panels.

**Context**:

- I have three Postgres datasources. For simplicity, say `A` contains ecommerce behavior, `B` contains app behavior, and `C` contains user profile data.
- I have a query on source `C` that helps me determine if the user is an enterprise, paid, or free user. Call the query `Q`.

**Situation**:

I am trying to filter out enterprise users from queries on `A` and `B`. So I need to apply `Q` to these tables.

Attempt at solution:

I have two library panels where I set the Data source `-- Mixed --`. In the first panel, I make a query to datasources `A` and `C`. In the second panel, I make queries to `B` and `C`. Note I am using query `Q` in both cases.

Woohoo!

**Problem**:

I would like to define `Q` exactly once to help future-proof changes.

Ideally, I would be able to use a `Dashboard` data source in a `-- Mixed --` context. How do I merge two `-- Dashboard --` sources?

Comment: What are  datasource types? Some TSDB offers cross DB queries, e. g. Redshift. What is cardinality of the Q result?

Comment: All data sources are Postgress -- will update the question

Comment: The easiest solution for this was to create "views" in Postgres and then call the views from grafana

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these can help you

- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/dashboards/json-model/
- https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/v9.0/dashboards/scripted-dashboards/

The basic idea is, make sure that you correctly set the `gridPos` and `datasource` properties in a way that make sense; and you can merge as many dashboards as you want by taking the `panels` (as mentioned in the docs, panels is an array of JSON that represents building blocks of the dashboard).

Hope it helps. I'm working exactly on the same right now.

Comment: Hi thanks for the info -- per the comment above, I ended up using "views" in postgres to achieve this end. Best of luck!